# Function definition not found (even if they exist)

Tags: c++, function, header, definition

Here's my main:

```
#include "terremoto.h"

int main(){
    std::string filename, zona;
    std::ifstream in_stream;
    std::ofstream out_stream;
    nodo *elenco, *filtroZona;
    std::list<Terremoto> elencoDoppio;
    float K;

    // caricamento dati tramite file
    std::cout << "Inserire nome file da caricare\n";
    getline(std::cin, filename);
    in_stream.open(filename);

    // elenco è la linked list con tutti i terremoti
    elenco = carica_elenco(in_stream);

    // filtro per zone tramite input da tastiera
    std::cout << "Inserire zona da filtrare\n";
    std::cin >> zona;
    filtroZona = filtro_zona(elenco, zona);
    std::cout << filtroZona;

    // copia di elenco in una double linked list (elencoDoppio)
    elenco_to_list(elenco, elencoDoppio);
    stampa_dlist(std::cout, elencoDoppio);

    // filtro per soglia di magnitudo tramite input da tastiera
    std::cout << "Inserire soglia magnitudo (filtra per >=K)\n";
    std::cin >> K;
    filtra_magnitudo(elencoDoppio, K);
    stampa_dlist(std::cout, elencoDoppio);

    return 0;
}
```

here's my terremoto.h:

```
#ifndef TERREMOTO_H
#define TERREMOTO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

const int MAX_TERREMOTI = 100;
const int DIM_DATAORA = 20;

class Terremoto{
    public:
        Terremoto();
        Terremoto(const Terremoto &t);
        ~Terremoto();
        Terremoto& operator=(const Terremoto &t);
        bool operator<(const Terremoto &other) const;

        void getDataOra(char *str) const {std::strcpy(str, dataOra);}
        int getProfondita() const {return profondita;}
        float getMagnitudo() const {return magnitudo;}
        std::string getZona() const {return zona;}
        std::string getAnno() const; 
    
    private:
        std::string zona;
        char* dataOra;      // 19 lettere "aaaa-mm-gg hh:mm:ss"
        int profondita;     
        float magnitudo;    // intervallo (0.0, 10.0)

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Terremoto &t);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Terremoto &t);
};

struct nodo{
    Terremoto value;
    nodo *next;
}; 

nodo* carica_elenco(std::ifstream &in);
void stampa_slist(std::ofstream &out, nodo* n);
float media_magnitudo(nodo *n, std::string anno);
nodo* filtro_zona(nodo* n, std::string zona);
void elenco_to_list(nodo *n, std::list<Terremoto> &l);
void stampa_dlist(std::ostream &out, std::list<Terremoto> &l);
void stampa_recenti(std::ostream &out, std::list<Terremoto> &l, int n);
void filtra_magnitudo(std::list<Terremoto> &l, float K);

#endif
```

and here's my terremoto.cpp:

```
#include "terremoto.h"

Terremoto::Terremoto(){
    dataOra = new char[DIM_DATAORA];
}

Terremoto::Terremoto(const Terremoto &t){
    dataOra = new char[DIM_DATAORA];

    zona = t.zona;
    strcpy(dataOra, t.dataOra);
    profondita = t.profondita;
    magnitudo = t.magnitudo;
}

Terremoto::~Terremoto(){
    delete dataOra;
}

Terremoto& Terremoto::operator=(const Terremoto &t){
    if (&t != this){
        zona = t.zona;
        strcpy(dataOra, t.dataOra);
        profondita = t.profondita;
        magnitudo = t.magnitudo;
    }

    return *this;
}

std::string Terremoto::getAnno() const{
    std::string dataOraString(dataOra);
    std::string anno = dataOraString.substr(0,4);
    return anno;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Terremoto &t){
    std::getline(in, t.zona, ',');
    in.getline(t.dataOra, DIM_DATAORA, ',');
    in >> t.profondita;
    in >> t.magnitudo;
    in.ignore();

    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Terremoto &t)
{
    out << t.zona << ","
        << t.dataOra << ","
        << t.profondita << ","
        << t.magnitudo << std::endl;

    return out;
}

bool Terremoto::operator<(const Terremoto &other) const{
    int year = std::stoi(getAnno());
    int otherYear = std::stoi(other.getAnno());

    return year < otherYear;
}

nodo* push_front(nodo *n, Terremoto t){
    nodo *temp;
    temp = new nodo;

    temp->value = t;
    temp->next = n;

    return temp;
}

nodo* carica_elenco(std::ifstream &in){
    nodo *n;
    Terremoto t;

    n = 0;
    while (in >> t){
        n = push_front(n, t);
    }

    return n;
}

void stampa_slist(std::ofstream &out, nodo* n){
    while (n && out){
        out << n->value;
        n = n->next;
    }

    return;
}

float media_magnitudo(nodo *n, std::string anno){
    float media = 0.0;
    int count = 0;

    while (n){
        if((n->value).getAnno() == anno){
            media += (n->value).getMagnitudo();
            count++;
        }
        n = n->next;
    }

    media /= count;
    return media;
}

nodo* filtro_zona(nodo* n, std::string zona){
    nodo *n2 = 0;

    while (n){
        if ((n->value).getZona() == zona){
            push_front(n2, (n->value));
        }
        n = n->next;
    }

    return n2;
}

void elenco_to_list(nodo *n, std::list<Terremoto> &l){
    while (n){
        l.push_back(n->value);
        n = n->next;
    }
    return;
}

void stampa_dlist(std::ostream &out, const std::list<Terremoto> &l){
    std::list<Terremoto> temp;
    std::list<Terremoto>::iterator iter;

    temp = l;

    for (iter = temp.begin(); iter != temp.end(); iter++){
        out << *iter;
    }
    out << std::endl;
    return;
}

void stampa_recenti(std::ostream &out, const std::list<Terremoto> &l, int n){
    std::list<Terremoto> temp;
    std::list<Terremoto>::iterator iter;
    int count;

    temp = l;
    temp.sort();

    for (iter = temp.begin(), count = 0; iter != temp.end() && count < n; iter++){
        out << *iter;
        count++;
    }
    out << std::endl;
    return;
}

void filtra_magnitudo(std::list<Terremoto> &l, float K)
{
    std::list<Terremoto>::iterator iter;

    iter = l.begin();

    while (iter != l.end()){
        if (iter->getMagnitudo() < K){
            iter = l.erase(iter);
        }
        else
            iter++;
    }
    return;
}
```

(Visual Studio Code)
Terremoto.h - from line 43 on:

- stampa_slist(...) : VSCode suggests "function definition for 'stampa_elenco' not found" (that's not the name of the function, I also tried rebooting but the error stays there.
- elenco_to_list(...) : Like above, but this time the function name is correct.
- stampa_dlist(...) : Again, it states "stampa_elenco()" is missing a definition, and again that's not the name.

When compiling, I only get an error with stampa_dlist(...) and it's the following:

undefined reference to `stampa_dlist(std::ostream&, std::__cxx11::list<Terremoto, std::allocator >&)'

found in the main, obviously.

Comment: re `stampa_dlist` only - the definition and declaration don't match `void stampa_dlist(std::ostream &out, std::list<Terremoto> &l);` vs `void stampa_dlist(std::ostream &out, const std::list<Terremoto> &l)`

Comment: Please try for a **minimal** example. Don't be concerned about functionality. Let's take `stampa_dlist` as an example since that is in the error while compiling. What happens if you remove every line from `main` that does not mention `stampa_dlist` (except the definition of its argument `elencoDoppio`), every function declaration from the header other than `stampa_dlist`, and every function definition from `terremoto.cpp` other than `stampa_dlist`? Still get the error? Good. Next up, try removing all the lines from the body of `stampa_dlist` and reducing your class to `class Terremoto {};`.

Comment: @JaMiT's comment is doubly helpful: following it would help you make your question clearer, better, and more beneficial for everyone; AND it is a nice way for you to understand the problem and potentially solve it on your own. :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten) suggested, there was obviously an issue with the "const" in the definition.
No matter how much you check, sometimes the combination of being completely new to CS and the need of a break really hit :D

Sorry for the stupid question, but thanks for opening my eyes ahah

Comment: *completely new to CS* has little to do with it. The brain sees what it wants to see sometimes. That's why I recommend putting the declaration and definition one atop the other and comparing them character by character. Right beside each other, the brain notices the differences, but if you have to look from here to there, the brain has time to go, "Yeah, yeah. I know what's supposed to be there, so I'll just fill in the blanks."